Does there exist a decent Python-to-English converter (abstractly, i.e. may not be coded on Earth) that is round-trip?
I was wondering how much Python can be converted in as close as possible a near 1-1 correspondence with English statements?
And how one could go about writing one given that they are able to examine a running AST of Python, meaning I took the AST from Python and wrapped every data object / method with one of my own that reports back information about the type, such as what types get assigned to it and whether it should be a CPP Variant type e.g.
In the documentation to the Python to English converter it is preferred therefore that you mark-up types with a:int = 3 for example.
Also assume that in English an Arbitrary-precision integer is simply a string of digits (note that int in Python is exactly that, but implemented in an optimized way).
So for example if the user calles dir(X) on an object $X$ in Python, then on the English side we would say "The dir of X is the following list: method1, method2, __add__, __init__, etc.
What are the hangups typically encountered when trying to accomplish this?
Notice that the same principle could even more easily be duplicated to make a CppToEnglishRoudtrip converter.  And therefore, you could theoretically build a Python to English to C++ roundtrip converter via program composition (running one program on the input of another).
This is a very tedious process usually, that takes months of coding just to convert a PyQt5 3D demo into a Qt/C++ one.  Also, many times it's much easier to implement something in Python.  But we all want the ultimate speed of C++, another use case.

Notice, we can make indentation on the English side 1-1 correspond with that on the Python side.  It's very useful to do that, and gives locality of variables.  Let's assume the English is Markdown, and includes KaTeX/MathJax capabilities.

Correction: the Python is 1-1 with a proper subset of an English/math document format.  So if you write in some nonsense in English, it will throw an error.  And although it allows multiple ways of saying something, these ways are recorded and fixed.  In other words conversion back/forth is deterministic.  So if there are multiple ways of saying something, we pick the shortest form as the canonical form and convert Python to/from that form.

Yes, this can be done quite easily, by reformulating all Python constructs as English in a standard way.
A good start would be to ask a screen reader to read the code and write the results down. The results will not be good enough, for two reasons:

They will be unnatural, because the screen reader doesn't know Python and will treat everything that isn't part of an English word as a loose symbol that it will simply name, e.g. x = [ 1, 2 ] will become something like ex equals sign square bracket open one comma two square bracket close, while we want something like to the variable named ex, assign the list consisting of one and two.
They may be ambiguous; for instance, the screen reader will not indicate the amount of indentation, and we need to make sure to distinguish x = [ [ 1 ], 2 ] from x = [ [ 1, 2 ] ].

Both can be remedied by manually redesigning ways of formulating every Python construct in plain English such that no matter how they are combined, the result is always naturally flowing English that unambiguously maps back to the original Python code.
For instance, [ [ 1 ], 2 ] can be formulated unambiguously as:

a list consisting of the following two elements: a list consisting of the following element: one, and two, or as
a list with elements: a list with element: one, and two, and no more.

This may even be done in such a way that Python programmers will be able to translate everything back into the correct Python with little or no training.
The hardest parts to do this for will actually be the non-code parts of the code: whitespace and the contents of strings and comments.  But of course we can always resort to literally naming all characters in sequence.
So this is possible, and COBOL took this approach to some extent. It may even be useful, namely, to blind programmers.
What this will not allow you to do, of course, is to throw arbitrary English sentences at the computer and expect it to translate them into Python. You will only be able to write using the very specific constructs you designed, and the meaning of what you write will be completely determined by the meaning of the Python code it is a superficial rewording of. It will be a very superficial "translation" into a very specific and rather mechanical "jargon", not into arbitrary English.

How much Python can be converted into English?  Approximately none.  English is not precise, is vague, is ambiguous, is open to interpretation.  Any attempt to convert Python to English is doomed to run into those issues, at least at corner cases, if not in more serious ways.

What about Python to CPP my next question?

I don't like your answer btw.  But I still upvoted.

@DanielDonnelly, Thanks for the comments.  The usual rule is to ask only one question per post, so I've answered your first question.  Part of our goal here is to build an archive of knowledge that will hopefully be useful to others, in the form of questions and answers, so if you have multiple questions, it's best to ask them separately.

Given an input like “abc def”, create the output “Start with the letter a, add a letter b, add a letter c, add a space character, …, add the letter f.”
If your input is a Python program, it gets translated into an English string, which is easily translated back to the original Python program. I’m not saying it’s useful, but it answers your question.
